# Using unit constants

Tags: php

How do you feel about using unit constants such as:

```
define("HOUR", 3600);
define("DAY", 86400);
define("YEAR", 31556926);
```

... so that you can do things like:

```
cookie::set("key", "value", DAY);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends. If the constants are used often, they may warrant their existence. I also generally prefer a constant over some number, as it can be given a somewhat descriptive name.

But, for multiples of common time periods, I think stuff like the following is generally very well understood at a quick glance, and sometimes more concise than some overly verbose namespaced constant. I'm assuming its common knowledge of how many seconds are in a minute, hour, and day, which I think is a decent assumption.

```
60 * 45; //45 min
3600 * 8; // 8 hrs
86400 * 100; // 100 days
86400 * 365 * 5; // 5 yrs
```

But if the constants are there...I'd probably use them.

Answer (score 0):

I do this a lot: so you don't have to re-type that "31556926", and maybe make a mistake.

(Apart from the fact that you've not defined MONTH :)  )

Comment: Months have variable lengths (although so do years)

Comment: @David Dorward, that's true. How would you set a cookie for a year?

Comment: Good point about the year! you might want to fill it with some sort of DATE function :)

Comment: for a cookie-of-a-year a day difference wouldn't matter that much?

Comment: You can account for time discrepancy over years by stating that there are 365.25 days in a year (365.2425 to be much more precise), rather than 365 days, which would be 31557600 seconds, and is the length of the Julian Year used in Astronomy.  A month in seconds could be loosely defined as 31557600/12 or 2629800 seconds (30.4375 days).